# jquery to update all elements after nth element?

Tags: jquery, css

Let's say I have the following code:

```
<ul>
    <li data-val="1">1</li>
    <li data-val="4">2</li>
    <li data-val="2">3</li>
    <li data-val="5">4</li>
    <li data-val="1">5</li>
</ul>
```

I want all items that are `ul li:gt(0)` to have a `innerHTML` with the sum of `data-val + innerHTML`.  So the result I want is:

```
<ul>
    <li data-val="1">1</li>
    <li data-val="4">6</li>
    <li data-val="2">5</li>
    <li data-val="5">9</li>
    <li data-val="1">6</li>
</ul>
```

I could use a for loop to do this, but not sure if that's the best way in terms of performance and in terms of minimally verbose code.   Is there a better way?

I can use jquery and css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) and pass a function which sums the two fields:

```
$('ul li:gt(0)').html(function() {        
    return $(this).data('val') + parseInt($(this).html());
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/infernalbadger/VJAza/